# How can I change the real directory to Python.exe in Spyder and PTVS?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I look at the Path Browser in IDLE, it points here on my machine.

```
C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
```

The code below works fine in IDLE
import pandas_datareader as web
df = web.DataReader('MSFT','google')
df.head()

However, in Spyder and Python Tools for Visual Studio I get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

It must be the engine that Spyder and PTVS are pointing to.  I can't figure out how to re-point these software packages to the right engine.  I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: `it still doesn't work` is not an accurate problem description. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out what the

> path that Spyder is pointing to

by running the following commands:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Ok.  Thank makes sense.  How can I change the path?  I tried this: SET PATH=C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\

It didn't work.

Comment: You can edit the PATH variable permanently in "Advanced system setting --> Environment Variables --> System Variables". The exact location of this configuration can vary slightly accordingly to you SO version (btw you need to *append* to the PATH, not replace it).

Comment: Under Tools > Preferences, I re-pointed the Global working Directory to where I want it to be, but it keeps going back to the old one, which is wrong and it doesn't work.

Comment: None of that works for me.  I restated my original question.

Comment: The *global working directory* is not related to the python interpreter. It is the directory you'll get if you call *os.getcwd()* (i.e. the working directory). To change the python interpreter in Spyder go to "Console --> Advanced Settings --> Use the following Python Interpreter".

Comment: (and then you can make it point to the same interpreter Path Browser is pointing to)

Comment: Thanks.  I did all those things.  I am still getting this message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: You should try to restart Spyder and run sys.executable again to check if the new configuration is working. Another approach would be installing pandas_datareader with the pip associated to the python interpreter you're using.

Comment: LOL.  After all of that, it still points to the wrong directory. 
import sys
print(sys.executable) 
C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe

Comment: I know 10 other programming languages.  I will never understand how this Python stuff works.  Whatever I think Python is doing, it just does the exact opposite.  LOL.

Comment: Your problem is not really related to the language, but just to system configs. It may happen with any languages. I see you're using Anaconda, so you should try to install the missing packages with conda. Just type 'conda install pandas-datareader' in a prompt and probably your problem will be gone.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, type 'where conda' in a prompt to find out to which installation the conda command is pointing to. You should be using the conda executable located in the same folder branch of the python interpreter in which you want to install the package.

Comment: So, I ended up closing Spyder, entering 'spyder --reset' no quotes, and restarted the app and it worked.  Also, if you open Anaconda Navigator > Environments > Not Installed and enter 'pandas', you can find what is NOT installed, click it to install it, and you're done.  NO MORE CRAZY PIP STUFF THAT DOESN'T WORK!!